# Can windows version affect a software's RAM and CPU usage?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, directx, cryptomining

I downloaded a software that uses simple D3D drawings overlayed on my computer screen. I noticed that the software was using an unreasonable amount of my RAM (about 8GB of RAM) and CPU (40% of my CPU). This led me to suspect that the software was mining cryptocurrency under my nose. When I asked the developer of the software for an explanation, he told me that it's because my windows version (currently 1803) needs to be updated to 1809. This just doesn't make sense to me. How can that cause the software to use 8GB for simple directx drawings? I could really use some help here.

My specs: 
processor: intel i7-6700HQ 
Memory: 16GB DDR4

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the software's author is lying?

Answer (score 0):

If the software doesn't have the windows features it expects, it could be compensating by working "harder"...

According to this page [DirectX Raytracing and the Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/directx/2018/10/02/directx-raytracing-and-the-windows-10-october-2018-update/) (apparently that was Windows update 1809) there were several updates to DirectX, if this program expected features that aren't in your older version it could be falling back to more cpu & ram intensive alternatives - you may even be lucky it ran at all.

You could try updating Windows & DirectX and compare the performance for identical tasks... but how do you know the program just doesn't require a lot of ram & cpu usage normally?